# Updating all with a dictionary in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dictionary

I have a small CMS-like program that has multiple `pages` that act like blog posts.  Each `page` has content, and a `position` integer that identifies in what order they will appear on the page.

On my admin side, I have a draggable list of pages that I can reorder similar to how wordpress orders plugins.  The page works as functions, and assigns the value of the dragged position to each `page` correctly.  However, since all sortable `pages` have their own form, I cannot submit them all at once - only one at a time.

As an example, my code looks like this currently:

```
<div class="sortable">
  <% @pages.each do |page| %>

    <div class="dragBox">
      <%= form_for(page) do |f| %>
        <%= f.number_field :position, class: 'inPosition' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Because I can get every `page_id` tied to its new `position`, is it possible to submit those values in a new hash to get updated all at once in the controller?  How would I go about doing this?  Is there a better or easier way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The easier way to do it would be to put them all in the same form using [`fields_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms).

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20120315004343/http://webtempest.com/sortable-list-in-ruby-on-rails-3-almost-unobtrusive-jquery

Comment: @Jordan would you recommend that I make a sort of "parent" activerecord container for all the pages, and then do something like `form_for(pages_parent)` and then `fields_for(page)`?

Comment: If anyone is wondering in the future - [this episode of railscasts helped a lot.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually) Just skip to the updating portion.