# Function for ranking cards by number and adjusting ranks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, logic

This is a bit of an open-ended question that's not language specific, though the code I'll ultimately end up writing will be Ruby/Rails.

I have a page in my app with a set of cards, each with some content. Each card has a rank attribute that's a positive integer. I'm working on a way for a user to reorder the cards by clicking an up/down button on the card, which requires adjusting the ranks. For example, if I want to move #2 up, I need to swap places with #1 (if there is a #1). If I want to move #1 down, I need to swap places with the last card in the set.

The problem I have is that I have a lot of bad data to contend with. A good chunk of my cards don't have ranks (`rank = nil`). Additionally, some cards within a profile aren't ranked sequentially. The ranks may be `[1,3,7,99,nil]` instead of `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Cards with a `nil` rank appear at the end of the list.

Writing a function to adjust the ranks of the cards would be fairly easy if the data was perfect, but that's not the case here. What I'm wondering is if there are any good resources on how to approach this problem. I want to make sure I'm accounting for all possible scenarios, such as what to do when I move a card with `rank = 4` up one space, but the card in the previous slot also has `rank = 4`.

As an additional challenge, this function will occur within a controller, so I'm looking for a way to boil down the complexity so that I don't have 100+ lines of code in a controller method.

**Answer with working code**

In case it helps anyone else, here is the working code I came up with for ranking cards with different classes:

```
def adjust_rank
    company = current_user.company

    # Build array of cards
    cards = []
    cards << company.office_card if company.office_card.present?
    cards << company.twitter_card if company.twitter_card.present?
    company.gallery_cards.each { |gc| cards << gc }
    company.quote_cards.each { |qc| cards << qc }
    company.wild_cards.each { |wc| cards << wc }

    # Ensure no cards have nil for rank before sorting
    cards.each_with_index { |c,i| c.rank = 100+i if c.rank.nil? }
    cards.sort_by! { |x| x.rank }

    # Ensure cards are ranked sequentially
    cards.each_with_index { |c, i| c.rank = i }

    # Save all cards in a single transaction. This works even though not all the cards belong to the same class.
    cards[0].class.transaction do
        cards.each { |c| c.save }
    end

    # This is the card whose rank the user is adjusting
    selected = Object.const_get(rank_params[:type]).find(rank_params[:id])

    # Get the adjacent card from the cards array
    if rank_params[:direction] == 'up'
        swap = cards.select { |c| c.rank == selected.rank + 1 }[0]
        # If there is no card after selected, get first card in array
        swap = cards[0] if swap.nil?
    elsif rank_params[:direction] == 'down'
        swap = cards.select { |c| c.rank == selected.rank - 1 }[0]
        # If there is no card before selected, get last card in array
        swap = cards[-1] if swap.nil?
    end

    # Swap ranks
    swap_new_rank = selected.rank
    selected_new_rank = swap.rank

    swap.rank = swap_new_rank
    selected.rank = selected_new_rank

    respond_to do |format|
        if swap.save && selected.save
            format.json { render json: {}, status: :ok }
        else
            format.json { render json: {}, status: :bad_request }
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Why don't all your cards have a rank?

Comment: The original developer didn't set a default value or make the rank field required and the content has been managed by many people. Over time this has resulted in bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar with ranking content.  I build a CMS in Rails that let the user order the position in which content was displayed.

To provide a more platform agnostic example, I'll be using some psuedocode.  I'll also be assuming you'll be using some sort of ORM like ActiveRecord.

### Rails side of things

---

Anyways, my solution was to have a hybrid Javascript/Backend approach.  I began by creating my `Card` Model.  The migration might look something like this -

```
create_table :cards do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.integer :position, :default => 0
end
```

Notice that I have a position.  This might seem redundant to an `id`, but I'll be using it to store the visual position of our object. Also notice that I have provided a default value to our `position` so we will never have bad data like the above.

So, let's pretend we have the following seed data -

```
Card.create(name: 'card1', position: 1) 
Card.create(name: 'card2', position: nil) 
Card.create(name: 'card3', position: 6) 
Card.create(name: 'card4', position: 5)
```

Notice how even though our cards may be labeled in order, their position can change freely.  If we were to get `Card.all`and sort them based on `position`, we would get a list that looks like this, assuming we are outputting their name.

```
card2 # position 0 since our default is 0
card1 # position 1
card4 # position 5
card3 # position 6
```

### Javascript side of things

---

Now, we want to be able to reorder our cards.  Since there are many solutions to creating a frontend, I'll be explaining this part more abstractly.

In this example, I will assume that each card is inside of it's own `div` element, and within that `div` element is a hidden form that determines the `position`.

Basically, when you click of of the arrows to move the item up or down in the stack of cards, you want to re-evaluate their position.  Code for that might look something like this:

```
function whenArrowClicked(){
    for every card div{
        this.form.val(i)
    }
}
```

So, our initial positioning of

```
card2 # position 0
card1 # position 1
card4 # position 5
card3 # position 6
```

will look more like

```
card2 # position 1
card1 # position 2
card4 # position 3
card3 # position 4
```

Which makes a ton more sense!

Additionally, if we were to do something like move `card1` up a position, our javascript would fix the positioning for us, so the `position` value reflects the visual value.

```
+ card1 # position 1 - used to be 2
- card2 # position 2 - used to be 1
  card4 # position 3
  card3 # position 4
```

Saving this form will update our objects and fix any objects that had a `nil` position to begin with.

---

Keep in mind that this is a very brief solution, and actual implementation has more details to take into account - for example, if you plan on having a huge number of cards, `Card.all` will not be an efficient way of grabbing content.  Also, you may run into a problem trying to save multiple Models at a time.  [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684905/updating-all-with-a-dictionary-in-rails) (see the comment).  However, hopefully this can help you get a starting point on how to construct your application.

Comment: So with your `whenArrowClicked` function, are you suggesting that I should make a pass through and correct all the data if the data is bad, before worrying about adjusting the position? That would seem to make more sense, to run a check like that each time before doing anything. Then I wouldn't have a 101 edge cases to contend with because I could be certain that each time I reorder the cards, they will all be ranked sequentially from 0 to whatever. Hmm, now the only challenge left is to come up with the query to do this, given there are six different card models. Thanks!

Comment: The only downside to that would be that its inefficient to check/correct the data each time. Given that each profile only has a dozen or so cards though, I think that's a fairly trivial concern performance-wise.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH When I did it, I used the jQuery UI library with DragDrop.  It ordered the HTML for me, and when I wanted to submit the data, *then* i'd do the check just once and submit.  It depends on how you set up the frontend.

Comment: I see. In my case the front-end is Angular. Each time a user clicks a button to move a card up/down the Angular controller hits the backend, which is basically a Rails API. I can probably mitigate the performance effects of correcting the data by running a check each time and only correcting the data if it's bad. Not super elegant but I'm not sure how else to enforce sequential ranking across six different card models.

Comment: Ah - unfortunately I'm not proficient enough in angular to give you a solid answer.  The only thing I could think of is to not update the actual backend database until the user is happy with their overall changes, as opposed to saving with each click.

Comment: In case you're curious, I just updated my post with the solution I've implemented. I'm sure I could improve on it, but it works, which is the important thing. Thanks again!